# Import DesignSpark project into Altium Designer

Tags: pcb-design, altium

Altium mention DesignSpark in their 'Import Wizard' documentation but apparently do not actually support it.
Does anyone know a method to achieve this?  
Would by some miracle DesignSpark have an export option to AD? or other package?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. Migrating legacy PCB docs into Altium. The easy part is importing the gerbers created by DS PCB into Altium D. However, no import method for schem capture exists. I'm re-creating the schem in Altium, parts and all, then having to netlist table the nodes corresponding to the nodes in the Altium PCB layout file. After that's all completed, I then export or output the Altium file as a package. Hope this helps.